# Radeon ignored, defaults to Intel GPU 16.04

Tags: 16.04, radeon, gpu, hybrid-graphics

Looks like my Radeon graphics card is ignored by Ubuntu. It's a 1GB graphics card and the person I last took help from confirmed that graphics card drivers are installed. He was talking about switching between onboard GPU and graphics card. But my understanding is we can use both. Am I wrong ? Only one resource can be used ? Help me out please..

Update :

Dell Vostro laptop

```
$ lspci -nn | grep -E 'VGA|Display'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0116] (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Whistler [Radeon HD 6630M/6650M/6750M/7670M/7690M] [1002:6741] (rev ff)
```

Comment: In a notebook with hybrid graphics you can't use both (and what would be the purpose of that?). Some desktop motherboards allow using ports from the integrated graphics along with the ports from the discrete graphics in a multi-monitor configuration. So, you need to [edit] the question and describe what your intended setup is and, of course, the hardware specifications.

Comment: @MichaelBay I don't understand your comment. You mean, one of them would lie idle ? I have system hanging issue when I used more than 2 applications. Why can't my system take benefit of my 1GB graphics card in such situations ?

Comment: Please post the hardware specifications, make/model at least.

Comment: @MichaelBay Post updated. It's a Dell Vostro laptop bought in 2010

Comment: You can use one or the other, not both simultaneously. Yes, drivers for both are installed by default. I don't know exactly how to switch graphics with the open source drivers (I don't use AMD; with Intel+Nvidia the switch is typically done via Nvida X Sever Settings) but most likely you'd have to use some command in terminal.

Comment: I want to allot the graphics card to resource intense applications. One or more. In my case, it's Firefox and VLC.

Comment: If you intend to use only the more powerful graphics (AMD) you may try directly at UEFI settings. Don't know about your Dell but many notebooks allow  selecting one (and disabling the other).

Comment: Do I need to fix it in BIOS ? Thanks.

Comment: Either way, you need to understand the purpose of hybrid/dual graphics: If only doing light work (and both Firefox and VLC are "light" in this context and for this matter only) Intel can be used thus saving power. Use the discrete  graphics (AMD) only for highly demanding software, for instance games and video editing/rendering, at the expense of battery.

Comment: *Do I need to fix it in BIOS*  If you're asking you still haven't grasped the issue. And you don't have BIOS, you have UEFI (some purpose but completely different, think about a horse carriage (BIOS) and a modern car (UEFI)). No, there's nothing to "fix" there. If available - as explained before - there are things to "set", not fix. Otherwise you need to toggle via software.

Comment: I have too many tabs on Firefox. It consumes a lot of resources ( as per system monitor )

Comment: In that case, I need to find out how to switch between the two. If on main power, I can do better with 1 GB AMD Graphics card than onboard Intel GPU, right ?

Comment: Right, but Firefox no matter how many tabs it has open, is NOT the issue. Worse case scenario it uses all the available (system) RAM, Ubuntu starts swapping a lot and that slows down the PC. It has little or nothing to do with graphics. Neither is VLC. The integrated Intel Graphics should be enough to play any content.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68706/discussion-between-user227495-and-michaelbay).